# Microsoft Help Viewer can be used as an independent Application?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, help-viewer

I have a machine with **Windows 8** where I've installed **VS2013** without **Help viewer**, and a *VirtualMachine* with the same *OS* and the same **VS** but with the **Help Viewer** package installed (`Help Viewer v2.1`).

I've create that ***VM*** with an unique purpose, I would like to be able to use ***Microsoft Help Viewer*** (or other alternative software, if exist) in my host *OS* without resinstalling ***VS2013*** in my *OS*.

...So in a very basic intent of reverse engineering to be able to use **Microsoft Help viewer** in my host *OS* I've just copied these folders from the *VM* to my *PC*:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Help Viewer
```

And

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\HelpLibrary2
```

And added these keys:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Help]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Help\v2.1]
"AppRoot"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Help Viewer\\v2.1\\"
"DefaultHelpViewerCLSID"="{FE220E43-FE17-47BE-A57E-84D2B9A5635D}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Help\v2.1\Catalogs]
"ContentStore"="C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\HelpLibrary2\\Catalogs\\"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Help\v2.1\Catalogs\VisualStudio12]
"LocationPath"="%ProgramData%\\Microsoft\\HelpLibrary2\\Catalogs\\VisualStudio12\\"
"LastUpdated"="02/26/2014 06:34:55"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Help\v2.1\Catalogs\VisualStudio12\en-US]
"SeedFilePath"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Help Viewer\\v2.1\\CatalogInfo\\VS11_en-us.cab"
"catalogName"="Visual Studio Documentation"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Help\v2.1\Setup]
"AppRoot"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Help Viewer\\v2.1\\"
"Install"=dword:00000001
"Version"="2.1.21005"
```

Notice the value:

```
"DefaultHelpViewerCLSID"="{FE220E43-FE17-47BE-A57E-84D2B9A5635D}"
```

I don't know what reffers that CLSID but a search on the registry of the VM with the search pattern `FE220E43-FE17-47BE-A57E-84D2B9A5635D` does not find anything (but the help viewer works properlly on the VM):

And I launch the Help Viewer (from commandline) with the same arguments as I get in the VM:

```
HlpViewer.exe /CatalogName VisualStudio12 /Locale en-US /Sku 3000 /LaunchingApp Microsoft,VisualStudio,12.0 /Manage
```

But when I press the `Update` button in the **Help Viewer** to download a package, just does nothing (of nothing) any error is shown or something else, just anything, so I can't download documentation or know what error I'm having.

Any idea to resolve this strange problem? maybe I need a missing component to copy on my host *OS*?

**Microsoft Help Viewer** can be just downloaded and installed as a standalone application?

Any alternative Software to replace **Microsoft Help Viewer**?

I've tried to use [H3Viewer](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4c360395-6afd-4087-94ed-cbcbebe04a20) but seems that it's only for VS2010, when I try to use the library manager the program says that I have not VS2010 Help installed.

> UPDATE:

I've solved the issue by downloading the documentation on the VM and copying them into my OS, but anyways I would like to know a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I recently faced the same problem: I didn't want to install "Visual Studio 2015" just to be able to run the accompanying Help Viewer (v2.2) application.

It took a little bit of time, but in the end I managed to get it running by following these steps:

- On a computer with VS2015 already installed, I used SysInternals [Handle 4.0](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/handle.aspx) to determine which files are required by the HlpViewer.exe executable
- I then ran [Less MSIérables 1.40](http://lessmsi.activescott.com/) and used its [`l -t File`](https://github.com/activescott/lessmsi/wiki/Command-Line#user-content-command-l-list) argument to iterate over all MSI packages, which revealed that most of the required files can essentially be found in two packages: **help3_vs_net.msi** and **vs_minshellcore.msi**.
- To install these manually, one needs to pass some additional command line arguments:
  `msiexec.exe /i help3_vs_net.msi VS_SETUP=1`
  `msiexec.exe /i vs_minshellcore.msi MSIFASTINSTALL="7" VSEXTUI="1"`

Regrettably, after that some files are still missing ... to keep things simple, I copied the rest of them from the (aforementioned) working installation:

- C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\HelpLibrary2
  Essentially only contains a **CatalogType.xml** and some empty directories.
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Help Viewer\v2.2\CatalogInfo\VS11_en-us.cab

Moreover, it's necessary to provide the application with a valid **ContentStore** path by importing the following .reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Help\v2.2\Catalogs\VisualStudio14]
"LocationPath"="%ProgramData%\\Microsoft\\HelpLibrary2\\Catalogs\\VisualStudio14\\"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Help\v2.2\Catalogs\VisualStudio14\en-US]
"SeedFilePath"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Help Viewer\\v2.2\\CatalogInfo\\VS11_en-us.cab"
"catalogName"="Visual Studio Documentation"
```

Finally, I created a new Application Shortcut and changed its **Target:** to read as follows:
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Help Viewer\v2.2\HlpViewer.exe" /catalogName VisualStudio14 /launchingApp Microsoft,VisualStudio,14`

Et voilà, with that HlpViewer.exe finally executes without any problems!

Comment: Addition: for non-English one can also install *Localization Package* between two msiexec calls: `msiexec.exe /i helpLP\help3_lp_net.msi VS_SETUP=1` from the non-English MS VS CommEd ISO

Comment: Update 2:  The possible problem: MS Help shows document trees, but not a single page of those - only the Welcome Page is stuck forever and can not be switched. Reason: reg-file. Your example ends with "VS11_en-us.cab" but actually one must look into the folder and see the actual files there! For me, after carving MS Help from MS VS2015 CommEd - those were "MSHelp3_1_en-us.cab" and "MSHelp3_1_ru-ru.cab" - the reg-file should reference any of those instead to make it work. I guess every user should see which cab files does their own installation carry.

Comment: This almost worked for me with MSVS2013 (Help v2.1). But there was still a dependency error. With the help of MSVS Remote Debugging I found that I also need to copy `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x86\Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.dll` (from PC with MSVS) to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Help Viewer\v2.1` (on PC without MSVS)

Comment: A moment ago just successfully installed on WIN10. Comfirmed that
Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.dll  not only must be copied to the target machine, but also need to be in GAC.
On WIN10 I cannot copy it to the help viewer's directory(prevent by OS)

My source help viewer comes from VS2013 update 3.

Comment: Awesome. I just wanted a way to launch it from a shortcut and you had the answer here. Thank you sir

Answer (score 2):

You ask multiple questions. I did not tried to reproduce so i can not answer your first question. But i can answer the title question:

Microsoft Help Viewer cannot be just downloaded. It is only shipped by Visual Studio and VS ISO Shell based products. So you cannot provide help content with Help Viewer for systems without Visual Studio... Kind of... useless :/

But on Windows 8 there is something similar so you can use some features of Help Viewer.

Source [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/645040ae-c4fc-4f2b-985b-8c25c9b84e77/ms-help-viewer-standalone-help-file?forum=devdocs).

---

Alternative Software: If you mean open the help files, I only know H3Viewer and some example projects where you can open files: [Help Viewer 2 Examples](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f08f296f-7076-4aec-8da3-8f0fbe04461e).

If you mean "take other help formats": the good old HTML Help (chm), MS Help (h2x) and a simple Website are some formats you can use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using VS2013, I solved this problem with this line saved as vshelp.bat file:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Help Viewer\v2.1\HlpViewer.exe" /catalogName VisualStudio12 /locale en-us
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes Microsoft Help Viewer can be used as an independent application, it comes with MSDN to USB v2.5 which makes management of MSDN docs much easier:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66595500/3268088