# How to download offline copy MSDN ( Microsoft help documentation)?

Tags: visual-studio, msdn

Can I download offline copy MSDN ( Microsoft help documentation) ?

For example I don't have internet access all day, but I need have access to the help infomation.

And how to do it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes.**

If to be short - just install [Microsoft Help Viewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh580782.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and inside it you can make offline copy all item that you need !

[image]
Full instruction you can find [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pakistan/2013/02/04/download-all-msdn-documentations-for-offline-access/)

Comment: Second link is broken

Comment: @Lisbeth - thank you very much - please use this https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2017-offline-books-available-for-download/ - microsoft has changed link

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can use [**MSDN to USB**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Moataz99.MSDNtoUSB), it works offline with any Visual Studio 2010|2015|2017|2019 IDE product.

Apparently, you've to download the docs 1st, then use this tool to "**Backup MSDN**" to your USB drive, later use the same tool to "**Locate MSDN**".

Comment: You need to install Visual Studio for using that ...

Comment: No, you can run Microsoft Help Viewer directly, without even having any VS IDE installed, but it's not practical.

Comment: Learned about a new useful tool.

Comment: @Alexander Now it doesn't, v2.5 already comes with Microsoft Help Viewer v2.3, no IDE required.